# Trouble with image

Tags: html, css

I have trouble trying to add an image right under the navigation bar. Tried to put the code inside HTML and the CSS index, yet the image end's up being inside the navigation bar. Any solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include your source code to make other people easy to help.

Comment: without your code we can only guess what is going wrong, and that won't be very useful. Try to make a minimal example that reproduces your issue and we'll be happy to help though. If you keep it like this, I'm afraid you'll question will get closed.

Comment: Include further information. Some code and/or screenshots would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this : `<img src="images/heard.jpg" alt="A Mic" width="600" height="450"/>` instead of this : `<img src="images/heard.jpg" > alt="A Mic" width="600" height="450" />`

Comment: This isn't even valid syntax